# Who says, "If you are going to Heaven, you will know it"?

Tags: soteriology, heaven

I heard from some preachers(not prominent) that assurance of going to Heaven is a self-consciousness. You yourself will have the evident, proof or confident that you are indeed going to heaven. If you are saved and are going to Heaven, you will know it. Some kind of consciousness will occur to you that Heaven is yours. Also, if you are not sure of your entry to Heaven, it means that you are not actually saved and are not going to Heaven at all. If you are saved you will know for sure that you are and if you have doubt about your afterlife, you are not saved at all.

**Is there any prominent preachers or theologians who teaches that having no confidence about our afterlife implies that we are not actually saved?**

Comment: If you see the Pearly Gates, you're "going to Heaven" and "you will know it".

Comment: @Narnian If I see the Pearly Gates, that means I'm dead! :(

Comment: Oh... you wanted to know before you die?  (I was joking.)

Answer (score 2):

The only prominent preacher I could find was Paul:

Hebrews 11 speaks of faith and even faith that leads to a “good report”.  What follows is Hebrews abbreviated to focus on the distinction of this question.  Do we have the benefit of assurance that was not available prior to the completed work of the cross?

> Hebrews 11 Now faith is confidence in what we hope for and assurance about what we do not see. This is what the ancients were commended for. By faith we understand that the universe was formed at God’s command, so that what is seen was not made out of what was visible…By faith Abraham…was looking forward to the city with foundations, whose architect and builder is God…All these people were still living by faith when they died. They did not receive the things promised; they only saw them and welcomed them from a distance, admitting that they were foreigners and strangers on earth…they were longing for a better country—a heavenly one. Therefore God is not ashamed to be called their God, for he has prepared a city for them…These were all commended for their faith, yet none of them received what had been promised, since God had planned something better for us so that only together with us would they be made perfect.

So faith and faith’s effectiveness in a relationship with God has ever been extended to mankind.  We who live on the other side of the cross are not unique because of our heavenly destination but that we have received the promise; we have the benefit of knowing whom to serve as Lord.  And as a result of Christ’s finished work on the cross we uniquely have the benefit of the Holy Spirits presence within our heart.  This unique presence of the promise enables Christ to be made manifest through our lives.

Faith in God’s grace saves the soul of mankind, assurance of God’s grace within the heart of mankind comes when we become less and He (Christ) becomes more, when we take up our cross and follow Him.

Evidence of His presence in our lives gives us assurance that we belong to Him, we are no longer our own.

Comment: I have seen many Christians who have no confidence about their afterlife. Does it mean they have no faith?

Comment: Afterlife is an interesting term, while generally it refers to after this life, it could refer to life after the realization of Christ.  We Christians sometimes get lost in determining our personal destination when we need to get on with Christ being made manifest in our life, generally understood as sanctification.